# Any way to save the bundle data

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am getting some data using Intent from A activity to B activity. And I show the text in B activity. But When I go to C Activity and I want to come back to B activity, the text that I have show there, vanished. So I need to save the data at B Activity When I come back from C Activity to B Activity.

Comment: Do you call finish() when you go from activity B to activity C?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences in this case. SharedPreferences offers a framework to save persistent data in key-value pairs. It works for any primitive data type which also means that it’s pretty simple to work with.

To get a SharedPreferences object:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref =
    context.getSharedPreferences("TheFileName",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Write into your SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("test", false);
editor.apply();
```

Read from SharedPreferences:

```
boolean musicState = sharedPref.getBoolean("test", true);
```

Comment: Is this is the only possible solution ?

Comment: for small amount of data it's best.

Comment: Sir I dont have 10 points. recently i posted a question. 1 or 2 user devote my question.

Comment: This is asking for trouble. You should keep the state associated with the instance of the activity that's being restored from the back stack (and let it be discarded once that activity disappears, i.e. app close or otherwise leaves the back stack). This answer will lead to unexpected states if 2 instances of B with different states are both in the back stack, or if B can be started without passing intent params.